# How to convert a ListedColorMap to a list of colors?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to use the newer `cycles` parameter: but it does not seem to accept a `ListedColorMap`. So how can the list of colors contained within a `ListedColorMap` - as represented by a `colormap` object - be extracted and then used instead?

Currently:

```
mpl.rcParams['axes.prop_cycle'] = plt.cycler('color',cmap)
```

This fails:

`TypeError: 'ListedColormap' object is not iterable`

The following does work - but then we lose the value of the original colormap which might be a `linspace` for example:

```
mpl.rcParams['axes.prop_cycle'] = plt.cycler('color',['r','g','b'])
```

[image]

This seems should be ridiculously simple: just how to get the conversions of the `colormap` to a list ..  but how to do it ?

**Update** The esteemed @unutbu provided the answer below  (`ListedColorMap.colors`) and here is the result.

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
In [136]: import matplotlib.colors as mcolors

In [137]: cmap = mcolors.ListedColormap(["w", "grey", "green", "red"])

In [138]: cmap.colors
Out[138]: ['w', 'grey', 'green', 'red']

In [139]: plt.cycler('color', cmap.colors)
Out[139]: cycler('color', ['w', 'grey', 'green', 'red'])
```

`cmap.colors` was found using [IPython's tab completion](https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/3/interactive/tutorial.html#tab-completion) to show `cmap`'s attributes:

[image]

Comment: thx - I should have added type hint for my `cmap` variable to gain the auto-completion and  achieve what you did here ' .  Hmm i now tried it and importing the type hint is itself tricky (and I did not figure it out..)  ah well.